# Android TalkBack announces "List" as "Fifty first"

Tags: android, talkback, roman-numerals, accessibility

I'm testing an Android app with TalkBack and the word "LIST" is being announced as "Fifty first." Apparently TalkBack is assuming the capital letters "LI" are roman numerals 51.

I do not have access to the source code but I want to know, are all capital roman numeral letters alongside "st" or "rd" (such as "XXIIIrd") automatically announced as numbers? is there a way to make TalkBack announce letters as roman numerals perhaps in the content description?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually TalkBack doing this. This is the TextToSpeech Engine doing this. The solution is fairly simple, download a new text to speech engine. If you'd like to know when it's going to do this stuff, you could dig into the Android Open Source project, and check out the default TTS engine code. Every once in a while I discover a new automatically expanded thing that makes me cringe, but I have yet to dig into the TTS engine code myself and see what exactly all of those are. Others I'm aware of (perhaps historically)

CA -> Certificate Authority

m -> Meters

s -> Seconds (5m 45s -> 5 meters 45 seconds????, LOLS)

You could also consider overriding the content description with the lowercased version of the text.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I look forward to searching through the open source code and running some more tests.